# Red "x" by easy difficulty in Zombies

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2, cod-black-ops-zombies

Does anyone know why there is a red "x" by easy when you change the difficulty to easy on zombies?

Comment: I did notice on Die Rise, if you play on normal some guy speaks to you from a speaker system. That was absent from easy.

Comment: It's like they punish you for playing on easy by taking stuff out?....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red 'X' indicates that the rounds will not count towards the zombies leaderboards.

These games *will* count towards your rank and progress however.

Comment: Can you still achieve the trophies under easy?

Comment: It depends on which DLC you are playing. AFIK you can get every Achievement/Trophy under easy except for the Easter Egg Achievements (Tower of Babble, High Maintenance, Pop Goes the Weasel)

Answer (score 0):

It his is a really simple answer, on multiplayer custom games if you change one of the settings you get a yellow star ( to state that the default settings have been changed) zombies version of this is the red tick. It also means that the score gathered from that game won't be added to the online leader boards! Hoped this helped :)